# How to use Yolo V5 in C# with a GPU?

Tags: c#, .net, gpu, yolo, yolov5

I spend the last days trying to get Yolo to work on my GPU. I tried using https://github.yuuza.net/mentalstack/yolov5-net, I followed their guide to use GPU and it didn't work. All other C# Yolo wrappers are not using the Yolov5 version and I want to use this one. So my question is, how can I use YoloV5 in C# (.net 5.0) with my GPU. Here is the code I used with yolov5-net :

```
using var image = Image.FromFile(path);

            using var scorer = new YoloScorer<YoloCocoP5Model>("tinyyolov2-8.onnx");

            List<YoloPrediction> predictions = scorer.Predict(image);
            using var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

            foreach (var prediction in predictions)
            {
                double score = Math.Round(prediction.Score, 2);

                graphics.DrawRectangles(new Pen(prediction.Label.Color, 8),
                    new[] { prediction.Rectangle });

                var (x, y) = (prediction.Rectangle.X - 3, prediction.Rectangle.Y - 23);
                graphics.DrawString($"{prediction.Label.Name} ({score})",
                    new Font("Arial", 40, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), new SolidBrush(prediction.Label.Color),
                    new PointF(x, y));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(outputPath);
            image.Save(outputPath);
```

The above code works, but it eats my CPU, and it's clearly not possible to use this to process many images fast.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
using var image = Image.FromFile(path);
var options = SessionOptions.MakeSessionOptionWithCudaProvider(0);
using var scorer = new YoloScorer<YoloCocoP5Model>("Assets/Weights/yolov5n.onnx", options);
```

make sure you installed CUDA toolkit and cudnn.
this code maybe work or not, i'm not sure but you can try this, that's all I can help

Comment: Hi! I wanted to know from where can I get this `Assets/Weights/yolov5n.onnx` file from?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Syed Shayan Hasan
there are couple options, you can convert your yolov5n.pt model into yolov5n.onnx format with following command:

**with gpu:**
python export.py --weights yolov5n.pt --img 640 --batch 1 --device 0 --opset 12 --simplify --include onnx

**without gpu, with cpu:**
python export.py --weights yolov5n.pt --img 640 --batch 1 --device cpu --opset 12 --simplify --include onnx

Running shell commands like:

> python export.py --weights yolov5n.pt --img 640 --batch 1 --device 0
> --opset 12 --simplify --include onnx

in a Jupyter Notebook environment requires a slightly different approach. In Jupyter Notebook, you can execute shell commands by prefixing the command with an exclamation mark (!). This tells Jupyter to run the command in the system shell rather than as Python code.